# Send big data with dsmigratedata command

Tags: linux, rhel, data

I want send data to remote server using this command but I dont know what is the syntax is that I can use for this command...

I'm using the command:

```
$ dsmigratedate -s user@remoteip -p 22 password
```

But it's not working. Can someone help me?

Comment: Can you explain what this command is, dsmigratedate? Is this the Tivoli tool dsmmigrate? http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/tsminfo/v6/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.itsm.hsmul.doc%2Fr_cmd_dsmmigrate.html

Comment: The command is for OS Solera, this OS is exclusively for this OS.